# There's a tiny space between the top of the page and my navbar. How do I fix this

Tags: html, css

Image of my problem
[image: Image of my problem]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #6b6b6b, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #5a5a5a, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.header-logo {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

.main-nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-content {}

.nav-element {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

.nav-element:hover {
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a style="margin-top:0;
            padding-top: 0;" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png" alt="Jacque's Logo" class="header-logo"> </a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav-content">
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

There's this little space as you can see on the picture. I can't seem to find a fix to it. Tried changing the margin and padding on many elements of the header, didn't work.
I even tried removing the picture/logo and the space was still the same.

Anyone have an Idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Tried doing *{ margin: 0; padding :0;} ?

Comment: Yes, but it messes up the entire document tho

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean something like:

```
.nav-content {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To remove the space above the navbar.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3xrj895/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #6b6b6b, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #5a5a5a, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.header-logo {
  padding: 0 16px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

.main-nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-content {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-element {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

.nav-element:hover {
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a style="margin-top:0;
        padding-top: 0;" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60" alt="Jacque's Logo" class="header-logo"> </a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav-content">
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: thanks, i even thought i tried this, turns out I didn't

Answer (score 0):

It is the anchor tag. You can avoid the space with setting `line-height: 0` and the add to the container `display:flex;`

```
a {
  line-height: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  display:flex;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
}
.container a {
  line-height: 0px;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #6b6b6b, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -7px #5a5a5a, 0px 7px 26px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.header-logo {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

.main-nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-content {}

.nav-element {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

.nav-element:hover {
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a style="margin-top:0;
            padding-top: 0;" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png" alt="Jacque's Logo" class="header-logo"> </a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav-content">
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```